# how to send two parameters via jQuery to MVC Action with Url.Action helper

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, arguments

I have been working on a MVC4 C# project and in my Razor view need to send two parameters to a specific MVC Action when the due button is clicked, I decided to use jQuery in order to send the two parameters.

This is the code in the click event:

```
$('#salir').click(function () {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action(actionName: "MostarOrdenInicioEmpleados", controllerName: "Home", new { id = Convert.ToString(Model.num_doc), grupo= Convert.ToInt32(Model.grupo)})';
});
```

and this is the controller where I need to send the two parameters:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult MostarOrdenInicioEmpleados(string id, Int32 grupo)
```

But this is the error in the Razor view:

[image]

Error text:

> Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments
>   have been specified

Could you please tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just saying: if you provide named arguments (in your case, `actionName:`, `controllerName:`), they have to come *after* non-named (aka fixed arguments).

In your case, you can simply fix this by making your final argument (`routeValues`) also a named argument:

```
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action(actionName: "MostarOrdenInicioEmpleados", controllerName: "Home", routeValues: new { id = Convert.ToString(Model.num_doc), grupo= Convert.ToInt32(Model.grupo)})';
```

Answer (score 3):

You've used two named arguments (with `actionName:` and `controllerName:` *before* you used a fixed (i.e. un-named, specifically positioned) argument (in this case, it's your argument starting with `new`, which you didn't name), whereas the error says you can only put named arguments *after* the fixed ones.

So either

a) change the order of the arguments so the named ones are last

b) name all the arguments, or

c) don't name any of the arguments and make sure they're in the expected order.